# using phps exec command to launch an application on the server

Tags: php, exec

I'm attempting to run an application on the server, invoking it from PHP using the following code.

```
$application = "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\ScanBoy\\DM ScanBoy.exe";
exec($application);
```

Right now the application is 'run' however it crashes instantly. If I just run the application (by double clicking the exe) it runs and everything is fine.

When the application crashes the only error I get is

> "*{application name}* has stopped working. Windows is checking for a
>   solution to the problem"

I have had this problem with running application via c# backend to a ASP.NET page. The solution there was to set the Working Directory. However in php / exec I am unaware of how to set this option.

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

1. Use `exec("cd myworkdir/ && D:\\Program Files (x86)\\ScanBoy\\DM ScanBoy.exe");` to change the working directory for that exec command (only)
2. Use the php `chdir()` function to change the working directory of the php process.

You can find `chdir` documentation here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php

Comment: thankyou, While I was waiting for a response I figured this out :) My next question is: Will I need to change the directory back to it's original WD after I init the application? will it make a difference to php / mysql if i do not?

Comment: No, you don't have to unless there was some file in the existing working directory that you were using. PHP/MySQL won't care.

Answer (score 1):

You can [chdir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) to change current working directory